# JAVA: return methods and setting parameters

Tags: java, methods, parameters, return

I am new to java, **how does returning value work?** I need to return the width of an `GLabel`, to use it in another method

```
private double createLabel(String text, int locX, int locY){
    double widthOfLabel = labelText.getWidth();
    return widthOfLabel;
}
```

(I've cut out the un=important parts) but this should return the width of the label.

**how do i use it within another method?**

```
private void  getWidthofLabel(){
    double name = ?????????
}
```

I tried some different stuff, but they all seem to just return `null`. One more thing when I get the return value of the `createLabel` method, do I have to set it´s parameters `(string,int,int)`? I don´t want that, but the debugger seems to force me to set them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the result of `createLabel` you will need something like:

```
double name = createLabel(text, locX, locY);
```

You **will have** to provide the parameters, otherwise you cannot compile the code. If you don't need them you can create an overload with no parameters:

```
private double createLabel(){
      double widthOfLabel = labelText.getWidth();
      return widthOfLabel;
}
```

but at this point I'm not sure what's going on in your code. :D

Answer (score 1):

The return call will be done like:

```
double name =  createLabel(text, locX, locY);
```

and if you define method like following:

```
private double createLabel(String text, int locX, int locY){
}
```

You would need to pass a `String` and two `int`. In case you want a variant where you need not to pass parameters; overload the method like:

```
private double createLabel(){
}
```

which you can call like:

```
double name =  createLabel();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function:

> ```
> double name = createLabel(text,locX,lockY);
> ```

where text is a string, locX and lockY is ints.
it is impossible to call a function without its parameters, unless there is another function with the same name (that's called overload method).

Comment: A function with the same name but different parameters is called an _overload_, not _override_.

Answer (score 0):

you can call like this

```
private void  getWidthofLabel(){
   double name = createLabel("label", 3, 5);
}
```